# need to script connection to telnet and send commands to remote device with no user input

Tags: terminal, network, applescript, remote-desktop, script

Ok I need some help making a script that will connect to a server and send 2 commands

Ideally I would have telnet 192.168.2.230 9993

and once it logs in (no user name or password required - the server is air gapped)

once the connection is created the script would send the following commands:

remote: enable: true

record: true

So far I can only get it to connect to the remote device - any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

### Expect

Mac OS X includes the command line tool [expect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html):

> expect - programmed dialogue with interactive programs

`expect` is ideal for scripted interactions with other tools, like `telnet`.

The following questions discuss how to use `expect` and `telnet` together:

- [How to automate telnet session using Expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250564/how-to-automate-telnet-session-using-expect)
- [expect script to automate telnet login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login)
- [Shell script successful telnet login, how to issue commands after that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148832/shell-script-successful-telnet-login-how-to-issue-commands-after-that)

### Connect and Send

The following shell script may be enough for your two commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 192.168.2.230 9993
send "remote: enable: true\n"
send "record: true\n"
```

There are a number of ways to use the above script. One is to save the script as a text file called `myscript.command`; opening the file will then launch Terminal.app and run the script.

Alternatively, the script could be wrapped in an Automator action or AppleScript.